# SSRS SUM columns with strings and Integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm currently working on a report in SSRS and I have the following:

```
Student   Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4
-----------------------------
Student A   1    1     0   L
Student B   2    3     1      
Student C   1    0     L   1
-----------------------------
 Total      4    3     1   1  <------ this is the result im trying to get
```

This is an attendance report where:

1 = present

0 = Absent

1 - 5 = # Family member attended

Blank value = " " value, Attendance not taken

L = Lateness

I'm currently getting a #error when I try to Sum the columns. Is there way where I can Sum the columns without including the blank values and the string 'L'. I search this forum and haven't had any luck . Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: I want to clarify that the report is suppose to display the blank value and 'L' string value . Unfortunately, I cannot make changes to the data source.

Comment: If you can not find another solution using report designer, what I usually do is get the exact data including sums from my SQL query/view and the report writer just writes it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it on either end

SQL - `SUM(CASE WHEN Day1 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Day1Total`

SSRS Func. - Multiple "True" values

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "1", 1,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "2", 2,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "3", 3,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "4", 4,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "5", 5,0))))))
```

The SSRS Function is checking the values in the specified field to see if they match the specified value ("1"), if that is true it will return a value of 1 if it's false it will be 0. Once it has checked each value it will `SUM` all of them together.

Comment: Hello bjones thanks for the input  I tried using SUM(IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = 1, 1, 0)) and I still get the #error. Can you help me understand what this function is doing. Thanks

Comment: yes I did. I forgot to mention that Student attendance can include numbers 1-5... not only 1's and 0's

Comment: Ok. With multiple true values you will need to nest your `IIF`s. See edit.

Comment: bjones you've been a big help and so far I'm testing and its working. I have another question if i want to add the totals for each day will I have to do the following:  =SUM(IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "1", 1,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "2", 2,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "3", 3,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "4", 4,
IIF(Fields!Day1.Value = "5", 5,0)))))) + SUM(IIF(Fields!Day2.Value = "1", 1,
IIF(Fields!Day2.Value = "2", 2,
IIF(Fields!Day2.Value = "3", 3,
IIF(Fields!Day2.Value = "4", 4,
IIF(Fields!Day2.Value = "5", 5,0))))))

Comment: Not sure I understand your question exactly, you mean to add days 1-4 together? That's one way to do it. You could also change your grouping. Or you could reference textboxes: `=ReportItems!textbox1.Value + ReportItems!textbox2.Value`

Comment: yes thats exactly what I mean so the totals for the days should be 9. Sorry for the noob questions where will i reference the textboxes.

Comment: In the expression of another textbox.

Comment: If I understand this correctly It should be =ReportItems!Day1.Value + ReportItems!Day2.Value+=ReportItems!Day3.Value + ReportItems!Day4.Value The calculation not correct when i try this

Comment: You need the name of the text box you want to add. For example, let's say the name of the textbox that has the total of 4 is textbox1. It will be referenced as `ReportItems!TextBox1.Value`

Comment: thank you again for your help I was able to calculate totals days and total for each student.

Answer (score 1):

In the data source for your report, instead of including `Day1`, add in

```
CASE Day1 WHEN '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END intDay1
```

Comment: Hello Skippy thanks unfortunately I cannot make changes to the data source. Although using Case statements will make it a whole easier to calculate totals